# How do i add custom fields in google search results?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, search, search-results

I want to display custom fields like how search results pointing to wikipedia.

For example, try searching ***[Tesla](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tesla)*** on Google and check the search results,

One of the search is like this,

[image: Search Results for Tesla]

See the red boxed content. If i have a website and would like to show custom fields like ***Number of employees*** how do i do that ? I checked [page source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla,_Inc.) of Tesla's Wikipedia page, these values doesn't show up in the meta tags of the page. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 5):

That happens automatically. Google extracts what it thinks are key bits of information from the page, without needing any special markup or configuration on the site owner's part.

It's likely an evolution of the [list and table snippets](https://search.googleblog.com/2011/08/new-snippets-for-list-pages.html) which started appearing around 2011.

Comment: You may help the machines by using proper table markup instead of fancy div designs, though.

Comment: Those particular bits of information might actually be taken from Wikipedia, as per the datapoints in the company detail card sometimes used in the results.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins The result is for the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @GDav, so it is. I'll open my eyes next time.